# Rails: scope using created_at date but not time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to show all orders from a user and sort them by date (without time) and then sort according to status using scopes. The closest way I have found is to do this, but I am wondering if there is a better way of doing it:

Model: order.rb

```
  ...
  scope :order_by_year, -> {order "EXTRACT('year' FROM created_at) DESC"}
  scope :order_by_month, -> {order "EXTRACT('month' FROM created_at) DESC"}
  scope :order_by_day, -> {order "EXTRACT('day' FROM created_at) DESC"}
  scope :order_by_status, -> {order shipment_status: :asc}
```

Controller: orders_controller.rb

```
...
    @orders = @user.orders
                   .order_by_year
                   .order_by_month
                   .order_by_day
                   .order_by_status
```

Answer (score 0):

You can order by using the date function if it is Postgres database,
like

`scope :order_by_created_date, -> {order("date(created_at) DESC/ASC") }`